# Seek bar and button don't work

Tags: android

I want to write a simple android application with `one button` and `one slider` : my `java program` is as following :

```
package com.example.android.apis.view;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextSwitcher;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

/**
 * Uses a TextSwitcher.
 */
public class TextSwitcher1 extends Activity implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory,
        View.OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    SeekBar mSeekBar;
    TextView mProgressText;
    TextView mTrackingText;
    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;

    private int mCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.text_switcher_1);
        setContentView(R.layout.seekbar_1);

        mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        mProgressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress);
        mTrackingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tracking);

        mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        updateCounter();
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
        mProgressText.setText(progress + " " + 
                getString(R.string.seekbar_from_touch) + "=" + fromTouch);
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTrackingText.setText(getString(R.string.seekbar_tracking_on));
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTrackingText.setText(getString(R.string.seekbar_tracking_off));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCounter++;
        updateCounter();
    }

    private void updateCounter() {
        mSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(mCounter));
    }

    public View makeView() {
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t.setTextSize(36);
        return t;
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
The method setOnSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) in the type SeekBar is not applicable for the arguments (TextSwitcher1) in this line : mSeekbar.setonSeekbarChangeListener(this);
```

I don't know what is this problem,would you please help me to solve it.
Thank you very much in advance, Stefan

Comment: it seems right, cleaning the project might be helpful

Comment: Thanks Arash. Yes I cleaned it already but it doesn't work.I want to attach my whole code but I don't know who can i attach my code to this page?Would you please send me your email to send you my whole code?Thank you very much.Stefan

Comment: Sorry, I can not see your email address in your profile because of it is private as you can not see my email address in my profile.Would you please write me your email address here.Thank you very much.Stefan

Comment: Arash,Please check your email.Thanks.have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using setContentView twice , so the First layout would be replaced by second and any referencing to your first layout would be null .

```
setContentView(R.layout.text_switcher_1);
setContentView(R.layout.seekbar_1);
```

for using another resource view inside of your main Layout , you should inflate that layout to a view then initialize it's child views like codes below :

```
    setContentView(R.layout.text_switcher_1);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layoutSeekBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seekbar_1, null);

    mSeekBar = (SeekBar)layoutSeekBarView.findViewById(R.id.seek);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    mProgressText = (TextView)layoutSeekBarView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    mTrackingText = (TextView)layoutSeekBarView.findViewById(R.id.tracking);

    mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher)this.findViewById(R.id.switcher);
    mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

    Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```